# Como sanitizar variable File en PHP

Tags: php, xml

estoy realizando un proyecto el cual debe pasar algunas pruebas de seguridad en el codigo. tengo un codigo que recibe un archivo XML para leer los atributos en PHP, y al pasarlo por en analisis de codigo me marca error por el input tipo FILE.
Este es mi codigo que tengo, se recibe el archivo y se manda a un metodo en el cual se abre y se leen sus propiedades

```
 if ($_POST['tipodocumento'] == 'Factura')
        {
            $objeto = new abreArchivo();
            $resultado = $objeto->abrirXML($_FILES, $_POST);

            echo json_encode($resultado);
        }
```

El error de seguridad me lo marca por la variable $_FILES. Me marca una posible solucion lo siguiente:

Considere el uso de una solución estática para los archivos en los que se permite la escritura, como una lista de archivos de escritura verificados o una solución de almacenamiento de archivos diferente, como una base de datos. Si es absolutamente necesario, limite el destino de escritura a una sola carpeta desinfectando correctamente las entradas proporcionadas por el usuario para establecer un nombre de archivo y establezca mediante programación la carpeta de destino. Considere complementar esto con una verificación para asegurarse de que exista un archivo o no, según los requisitos comerciales del código de la aplicación.

Pero yo no guardo ese archivo si no que solamente leo los atributos del XML.

Alguien podria ayudarme a saber como recibir estos input files de una forma segura? o que es lo que tengo mal en mi codigo que es inseguro?

Comment: ¿Cuál analizador de código es? ¿Qué hace `abrirXML()`?

Comment: checkmarx, y el metodo abrirXML abre el XML recibido y va leyendo sus atributos y los valida